# Divide an image into overlapping blocks using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to divide an image into overlapping blocks. For example, 256x256 image is divided into (256-16+1)x(256-16+1)=58081 overlapping blocks of size 16x16. Please let me know how to implement this example using MATLAB?

Comment: Look into [`im2col`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) with the `'sliding'` option.

Comment: Check also [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html). With adequate input options you can have sliding blocks

Comment: Yes, this answer seems very helpful to me. Please help me out in defining the function handle used in blockproc function to do the implementation of example I asked in the question.